# Need help on THREE.js TextGeometry

Tags: three.js

Not sure why following code (basically a cut & paste from example) is returning error.

var textWhy = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Why", { size: 10, height: 5, curveSegments: 6, font: "helvetiker", weight: "normal", style: "bold" });

Cannot read property 'normal' of undefined

I am new to webgl, hope someone can point me to a solution.

Thanks.

Tried with this simplest snippet. Result is the same.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Three.js Why Text</title>
<script src="typeface-0.15.js"></script>
<script src="helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
<script src="helvetiker_bold.typeface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        textWhy = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Why", { size: 10, height: 5, curveSegments: 6, font: "helvetiker", weight: "normal", style: "normal" });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try 'regular' instead of 'normal'. BTW `weight` should be 'bold', not a `style`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I tried changing weight to "regular" or "bold". Both return errors saying "regular" or "bold" is undefined.

Comment: open an console on http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html and try :                                               
var textWhy = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Why", { size: 10, height: 5, curveSegments: 6, font: "helvetiker", weight: "bold", style: "regular" });

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolution' of undefined

Comment: I suppose, you need to load that font some way... but it's better just debug it.

Comment: Sorry ... forget about `regular`. It works for me with `weight: "normal", style: "normal"` and `weight: "bold", style: "normal"`.

Comment: thanks for your info, would it be possible to share your full page/code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found that I should not use "typeface-0.15.js" but only the font helvetiker_*.typeface.js. The 'load' function is provided in Three.js. So it should be:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Three.js Why Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Three.min.js"></script>
<script src="helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
<script src="helvetiker_bold.typeface.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: Worth clarifying that the fonts must be loaded _after_ Three.js (as you have it here). Took me quite a while to realise that ;)

Comment: Also I suggest the OP accept your answer (with this clarification).